# Intercept and log httpRequest and response within my .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, logging, httprequest, tracking

I need to create a class that enable to Intercept httpRequest within the application (so no need for proxy) and log request and response details. 
Create HttpRequest can created using any way (HttpClient, HttpWebRequest, Helper library like RestSharp .. anything), that's way I hope to create dynamic class contains event that fire when HttpRequest initialized.

I already use Network Tracing but all I can log are strings, So Is there a safer way to intercept request and response objects instead of parsing strings

```
public class DebugTraceListener : System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("D:\\Log\\log2.txt"))
        {
            Log(message, w);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("D:\\Log\\log2.txt"))
        {
            Log(message, w);
        }
    }

    public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
    {
        w.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
        w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Network tracing"? If you enable `<switch name="System.Net" value="verbose"/>` in `<system.diagnostics>` then you will have both requests and responses. About format: it will log using standard .NET mechanism then you can write your own listener (if you do not like standard `TextWriterTraceListener` format). Of course you need to _understand_ log messages if you want to interpret them.

Comment: I used this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6sbz1dx(v=vs.110).aspx .. so I can control on the output format if I write my Own listner ?!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti And Can I do everything using code not web.config ?

Comment: Yes, [you can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that to change _format_ you may need to _parse_ diagnostic output from System.Net classes (and it may change over time...). Maybe not the easiest task if you need a high level customization.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I create a customer listner extend from TextWriterTraceListener but the  request and response passed as strings and I will have to parse everything and remove extra strings that I don't need .. etc, Is there a more safe way to intercept request and response in a lower level than strings.

Comment: Yes, that's the _annoying_ part. You just get what System.Net classes want to log. AFAIK there isn't a lower level generic hook to inspect raw data but 1) format is fixed and should be easy to interpret (there is a description somewhere on MSDN), not much different than raw packet data and 2) update your question with this attempt and wait, maybe someone else knows another way to go!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using asp.net webforms or asp.net mvc. You need to create a class which extends the class HttpApplication and implements the interface IHttpModule

I have created the following module:

```
using System.Web;


namespace WebApplication1.App_Start
{
using System;

public class RequestHandler : HttpApplication,IHttpModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a module and prepares it to handle requests.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">An <see cref="T:System.Web.HttpApplication"/> that provides access to the methods, properties, and events common to all application objects within an ASP.NET application </param>
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {

        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += context_RequestCompleted;
    }

    void context_RequestCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var context = application.Context;

        var response = context.Response;
        context.Response.Write(response.Charset);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var context = application.Context;

        var url = context.Request.Url;
        context.Response.Write(url.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes of the resources (other than memory) used by the module that implements <see cref="T:System.Web.IHttpModule"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }



}
}
```

Next, register the HttpModule in your web.config by adding the following line in under :

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add name="Handler" type="WebApplication1.App_Start.RequestHandler"/>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Every request you make, it will write the url and the charset of the response received.

replace the following line by your logging instructions:

```
context.Response.Write(url.AbsoluteUri);
context.Response.Write(response.Charset);
```

for e.g.:

```
Logger.Log(url.AbsoluteUri) //in context_BeginRequest
Logger.Log(response.ContentType) //in context_RequestCompleted
```

You can log different attributes of the **response** and **url** variable which i have defined above.

Hope it helps

Comment: I need to create a Helper class, It can be used in any .Net application invoke web service (Web, Windows, Console .. anything )